# How to split appended data so it can be separated into two different columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

This code appends the last two fluctuations of odds for a particular runner. This is displayed in 'flucs3'. I want to split the data in 'flucs3' so it can be separated into separate columns in a dataframe - a column for 'Fluc 1' and a column for 'Fluc 2'.

My code:

```
request2 = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId=1051322&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
json2 = request2.json()
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for fluc in selection['flucs'][0]:
        flucs1 = ast.literal_eval(selection['flucs'])
        flucs2 = flucs1[-2:]
        flucs3 = [[x[1]] for x in flucs2]
        data.append(flucs3)
```

Output of df3:

```
[[7.63], [7.68]]
[[6.89], [6.9]]
[[6.89], [6.93]]
[[21.04], [20.96]]
[[15.35], [15.43]]
[[18.7], [18.72]]
[[9.83], [9.78]]
[[17.92], [18.07]]
[[26.13], [26.54]]
[[9.13], [9.16]]
[[9.99], [10.08]]
[[8.33], [8.34]]
[[13.9], [14.1]]
[[10.72], [10.85]]
```

Desired output of dataframe:

```
Flucs 1   Flucs 2
7.63      7.68
6.89      6.9
6.89      6.93
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the values in a list if you don't want them in a list?

Comment: `flucs3 = [x[1] for x in flucs2]`

Comment: This produces [9.05, 9.08]
[8.55, 8.45]. How do I separate the values now?

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack all sublists in your data list into another list(final_list), from which you can create two other lists (one for elements with odd indices i.e Flucs 1 and the other for elements with even indices i.e Flucs 2). Like this:

```
final_list = (list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))))         

flucs1 = [x for x in final_list if final_list.index(x)%2==1]
flucs2 = [x for x in final_list if final_list.index(x)%2==0]
output = list(zip(flucs1, flucs2)) #a list of tuples of items with corresponding indicies in both list
print('Flucs1', '\t', 'Flucs2')
for i,j in output:
    print(i, '\t',j)
```

> Result

```
Flucs1   Flucs2
9.08     9.05
8.45     8.55
7.55     7.45
37.38    36.62
18.78    18.55
14.89    14.97
10.02    10.09
17.05    16.97
30.77    30.38
9.89     9.82
9.89     9.82
9.61     9.78
8.9      8.91
13.83    13.82
```

You may also form your lists in a dictionary and dataframe the dictionary using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'Flucs 1': flucs1, 'Flucs 2': flucs2}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `from_records`:

```
data = []
request2 = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId=1051322&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
json2 = request2.json()
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for fluc in selection['flucs'][0]:
        flucs1 = ast.literal_eval(selection['flucs'])
        flucs2 = flucs1[-2:]
        flucs3 = [x[1] for x in flucs2] #Note: remove extra brackets from here
        data.append(flucs3)

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['Flucs 1', 'Flucs 2'])
```

Output:

```
    Flucs 1  Flucs 2
0      9.05     9.08
1      8.55     8.45
2      7.45     7.55
3     36.62    37.38
4     18.55    18.78
5     14.97    14.89
6     10.09    10.02
7     16.97    17.05
8     30.38    30.77
9      9.82     9.89
10     9.82     9.89
11     9.78     9.61
12     8.91     8.90
13    13.82    13.83
```